# How can I disable constant folding in Perl?

Tags: perl, compiler-optimization, constantfolding

Given a command like,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -E'use constant FOO => 42; print FOO()'
```

How can I disable constant folding such that

```
print 42;
```

Shows me

```
print FOO();
```

Or the like. **Ideally, I would like this to be a compiler option that works for all of Perl**. You can see this talked about in this thread on the perl mailing list, [*[perl #97942] [PATCH] Add `-DO` option to disable optimizations and disable constant folding and the peephole optimizer when used.*](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2011/11/msg179946.html). I tried `-DO` and it didn't work. If that option doesn't work, I'm open to workarounds however they may come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you can do is to prefix the constant with `&`,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -E'use constant FOO => 42; print &FOO()'
```

From the docs on `perldoc perlsub`

> **Constant Functions**
> Functions with a prototype of "()" are potential candidates for inlining. If the result after optimization and constant folding is either a constant or a lexically-scoped scalar which has no other references, then it will be used in place of function calls made without `&`. Calls made using `&` are never inlined.

Answer (score 3):

Constants present themselves as subs. Things you can do with a sub:

- Call it as a function (`FOO`, `FOO()`)
- Call it as a function while overriding prototypes (`&FOO()`)
- Call it as a function while inheriting `@_` (`&FOO`)
- Call it as a method (`__PACKAGE__->FOO`)
- Create a reference to it (`\&FOO`, `*FOO{CODE}`. Also `*FOO` where a code ref is expected.)

Only the first gets folded. As such, you could use

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say &FOO()' 2>&1 | grep FOO
5  <#> gv[*FOO] s
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say &FOO' 2>&1 | grep FOO
5  <#> gv[*FOO] s
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say __PACKAGE__->FOO' 2>&1 | grep FOO
6  <.> method_named[PV "FOO"] l
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say+ (\&FOO)->()' 2>&1 | grep FOO
5  <#> gv[*FOO] s
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say *FOO{CODE}->()' 2>&1 | grep FOO
5  <#> gv[*FOO] s
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E'use constant FOO=>42; say *FOO->()' 2>&1 | grep FOO
5  <#> gv[*FOO] s
```